# Algebra problem of Natural numbers

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers

i faced this problem and i am not sure that my solution is right:

i have these 2 equations:
Let $a,b \in \Bbb{N} $

1. a+b=n
2. a*b=(n-1)

how can i prove that the only answer is when a=1 and b=(n-1)
or vice versa,

many thanks

Comment: Construct quadratic equation with roots as a And b.i.e $$x^2-nx+(n-1)=0$$ $$(x^2-1)-n(x-1)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

If you add 1 to equation 2) you get $a+b=n=a\cdot b+1$. The equation $a+b=a\cdot b+1$ is equivalent to $a-a\cdot b+b-1=0$, which is equivalent to $a(1-b)-(1-b)=0$, where you can factor by $1-b$ and get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2=4ab$$
$$n^2-(a-b)^2=4(n-1)$$
$$(a-b)^2=n^2-4(n-1)=(n-2)^2$$
$a-b = n-2$ or $2-n$

Now you can solve the two equations.

Answer (score 0):

From 1, $b=n-a$; from 2, $a(n-a)=n-1$, that is
$$
a^2-na+n-1=0
$$
Can you solve the quadratic equation?